# PHP to LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE does not work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

I have look at some of the previous posts for the exact same issue, but was still not able to resolve the issue. I think my problem may be different than others. I think it may be a file permissions issue or something related to the location of the file or path. Maybe it's a MacOS sandboxing issue? This statement works just fine in MySQL Workbench. I am running MySQL 5.7.19 on MacOS 10.12.6. Any ideas???

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$port=3306;
$socket="/tmp/mysql.sock";
$user="user";
$password="password";
$dbname="Test_Company";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/Test.User/Desktop/Data/Inventory Data.csv'
    INTO TABLE inventory data
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
    IGNORE 1 LINES " ; 

if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($field1, $field2);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    //printf("%s, %s\n", $field1, $field2);
}
$stmt->close();
}

$con->close();

?>
```

Seems like it should be pretty simple and straight forward, but cannot figure this one out...

Comment: There is a missing `";` from the end of the `IGNORE 1 LINES`

Comment: Unfortunately I just forgot that in my post, but it's in the PHP script I am trying to run. Still no luck...

Comment: Can you update the script with all the code - there is nothing in your code which executes the SQL.

Comment: Sorry about that... This is the PHP code that was generated from MySQL utility, so this is what I am using.

Comment: Does the `$stmt->execute()` produce any error? Afaik `LOAD DATA INFILE` is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, the `LOAD DATA INFILE` options is not enabled by default. You have to enable it before running a `LOAD DATA INFILE` query:

```
$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
$con->options(MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, TRUE);
//
// $stmt = $con->prepare($sql); 
// etc...
```

Comment: Before posting my question, I did confirm that LOAD DATA INFILE was enabled. I went ahead and added the $con->options(MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, TRUE); and tested and still no data. Also, the PHP does not produce any errors. I wish it would, that would help...

Comment: Does `$stmt->execute()` return `TRUE`?

Comment: Hmmm... does `LOAD DATA` work with `prepare()`? Try to run it directly as `$con->query($sql)`.

Comment: As for does `$stmt->execute()` return `TRUE?`, I am not sure how to tell. I'm not getting any errors. I tried to run `$con->query($sql)` directly as you suggested and still no luck. I know it seems crazy, I cannot see any reason why it would not work..

Comment: Just as an additional note, I have another PHP script that clears the database table. When I add data to the table via MySQL then run the PHP script to clear the database, it works. The PHP code is exactly the same, except I have just replaced the ' $query = "TRUNCATE TABLE `Test_Company`.`inventory data `"; ` with the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement. So, I should be getting connected to the database. This issue seem to be with loading the data. That's why I think it could be somehow related to the file path or permissions.